# Can example be modified to return a value?

Tags: java, clojure

Given the following sample from JNotify, I am having a little trouble understanding *implements*. Is it valid Java syntax for `class Listner` to implement JNotifyListener's methods -- `fileRenamed`, `fileModified`, and so on -- but modify the return type from void to Integer?

I want to wrote a Clojure library on top of JNotify and have Clojure code block on a future, until one of Listener's methods returns.

```
  class Listener implements JNotifyListener {
    public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName,
        String newName) {
      print("renamed " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
    }
    public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
      print("modified " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }
    public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
      print("deleted " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }
    public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
      print("created " + rootPath + " : " + name);
    }
    void print(String msg) {
      System.err.println(msg);
    }
  }
```

Comment: No, you can't change a method signature like that when you're implementing an interface, otherwise people wouldn't know what to expect from the method (the whole point of an interface is so you know what to pass and what to expect back)

Comment: If the interface expects `void`, the implementation must returns `void`.

Comment: You could use a adapter pattern - wrap the `JNotifyListener` in another `class` that returns values.

Comment: @bmorris591  Or conversely, wrap the class that returns values in another that doesn't.

Comment: @MelNicholson yup, or that. Some wrapping is certainly involved...

Comment: @bmorris591 Could you expand on this in an answer? I can see implementing other methods not part of Jlistener and have them modify Listener scope data. Another method could check a value that each of the void routines could modify. Seem reasonable?

Comment: Sorry, octo.  That's violating the abstraction barrier.  It's exactly what interfaces are supposed to protect against.  You can sometimes get around that with casting, but at that point you are better off not using the interface at all.

Comment: I guess maybe there has been some gun jumping. It really depends what you want to do - where do you need to return values to? Could that class implement the interface?

Comment: @bmorris591 Without tinkering with anything illegal, I'd like to have these methods write class local data structures; write other methods in the class that do not implement JNotify's methods; and have those methods check class scope data for notification.

Comment: That sounds fine.  You should be able to do all that without changing the signature, though.  Why do you want to return a value?  And to what?

Comment: @MelNicholson I want Clojure code to have a future in data (that hasn't been defined yet) in this class. The Clojure code can block until a value is returned.

Comment: Why not forward the event to the other classes via an Observer pattern. Create an `Event` that encapsulates the data. Create an `interface` the has a `notify(Event event)` method. Register implementations of the `interface` to a `List` in the `JNotifyListener` and then call the `notify` method on all registered listeners. If you want something to block you can use `synchronized` and `wait`/`notify`.

Comment: @MelNicholson One of my problems is I am not fluent in Java. So, I'll go look up your suggestions.

Comment: Here's the reference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The return value type in the signature of an implementation must match the return value type of the interface it implements either with an exact match or with an implementing/extending type.

---

Response to comment (not to original question)

```
interface I {
  A foo();
}
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C implements I {
  public B foo() { return null; }
}
```

The Java 6 Compiler accepts the code above, which implies the return value is covariant at override time, so the commenters are correct that the match need not be exact.

Comment: That's true only in the case of primitives, and void. For reference types, the return type is actually co-variant (while overriding).

Comment: edited to clarify I was talking about the signature.  Obviously an extension or implementation can be returned as a match of the formal type.

Comment: e.g. `public C m()` overrides (or implements) `public P m()` if `C` is-a `P`.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung Same answer applies to Java7.  Implementation signature require an exact match.  It's part of the signature hash assumption underlying all JVM virtual method retrieval and would be a total PITA to ever change.

Comment: Sorry guys, it is very clear in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) - "An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This is called a covariant return type". This answer is just wrong. Moreover your code compiles fine.

Comment: I need to retract part of that...return value isn't part of the signature hash.

Comment: The point is, and why it compiles, is that the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) applies in this case. Anywhere where a method expects an `A` is can receive a `B` and not notice. If we were talking about the _parameters_ then we would need **contra**variance; java doesn't support that.

Comment: Exactly right.  I actually worked on the Java 0.9 reference compiler, and this was true back then too.  Major brain fart.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Oh, and the reason the original didn't compile was the lack of a return statement, which is not really relevant to the discussion.  The code you see now is already corrected.

Answer (score 3):

In response to clarifying comments from the OP:

Right, here is a quick example of an Observer pattern:

```
public interface JNotifyListener {

    void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName, String newName);

    void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name);

    void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name);

    void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name);
}

public enum Type {

    RENAMED,
    MODIFIED,
    DELETED,
    CREATED;
}

public class FileChangeEvent {

    final Type type;
    final int wd;
    final String rootPath;
    final String name;
    final String newName;

    public FileChangeEvent(Type type, int wd, String rootPath, String name, String newName) {
        this.type = type;
        this.wd = wd;
        this.rootPath = rootPath;
        this.name = name;
        this.newName = newName;
    }

    public FileChangeEvent(Type type, int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        this(type, wd, rootPath, name, null);
    }

    public int getWd() {
        return wd;
    }

    public String getRootPath() {
        return rootPath;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNewName() {
        return newName;
    }
}

public interface FileChangeEventListener {

    void notify(FileChangeEvent fileChangeEvent);
}

public class FileChangeEventNotifyer implements JNotifyListener {

    final Collection<FileChangeEventListener> listeners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<FileChangeEventListener>();

    @Override
    public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName, String newName) {
        notifyAll(new FileChangeEvent(Type.RENAMED, wd, rootPath, oldName, newName));
    }

    @Override
    public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        notifyAll(new FileChangeEvent(Type.MODIFIED, wd, rootPath, name));
    }

    @Override
    public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        notifyAll(new FileChangeEvent(Type.DELETED, wd, rootPath, name));
    }

    @Override
    public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
        notifyAll(new FileChangeEvent(Type.CREATED, wd, rootPath, name));
    }

    private void notifyAll(final FileChangeEvent changeEvent) {
        for (final FileChangeEventListener changeEventListener : listeners) {
            changeEventListener.notify(changeEvent);
        }
    }

    public void registerListener(final FileChangeEventListener eventListener) {
        listeners.add(eventListener);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(final FileChangeEventListener eventListener) {
        listeners.remove(eventListener);
    }
}
```

You can see that a `class` only need implement `FileChangeEventListener` and register its interest with the main `FileChangeEventNotifyer`. It will then have its `notify` method called with the event.

There are a couple of common pitfalls here. One is that this implementation does not use `synchronized`, therefore it is possible for a class to miss a notification if it is being registered as the event is happening. The advantage is that this is non-blocking. So it's up to you to work out whether it's preferable to have a non-blocking collection or a blocking one.

Also you either need to ensure that any registered listeners are unregistered afterwards otherwise they will pile up and you may end up with a memory leak.

I have implemented this as a single `FileChangeEvent`  with a `Type` - obviously you could have a parent `FileChangeEvent` class and then extend it with subclasses for types. Again it depends on what your needs are.

Anyway, this should get you started.

Comment: Nice example, bmorris.  To octo, The Guava class `ListenableFuture` is also worth looking at before you become too invested in a vanilla `Future`

Answer (score 0):

From the Clojure side, consider using promise/deliver rather than future.  Then the methods in the Listener can deliver to the promise.  http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/promise

If this is for a library, it might be better to pass a function in rather than using either future or promise.  This will allow the user of the library to pass in their own closure rather than having to introduce another thread change.